# Dynamic redirect in package route

Tags: laravel-4, routes, package

I have defined a route action with some business logic, inside an internally developed package. Depending on the result in this action, the app want to redirect the user to some dynamic route (`Redirect::route('admin.index', [$app->id])` e.g).

How would I do this?

Any solution I come up with doesn't work because of the way Laravel handles routes.

Right now I have copied the route to the app routes.php, and extracted the business logic to a method inside the package. But this is not optimal, as I'd like to also keep the route inside the package.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has some documentation on [Package Configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-configuration) that should work for you.

In your package's *src/config/config.php*:

```
<?php
return array(
    'route_admin_index' => 'admin.index',
);
```

Change your package's code to:

```
Redirect::route(Config::get('your_package_name::route_admin_index'), [$app->id]);
```

Now when installed on different environments, you can do:

```
php artisan config:publish your_vendor_name/your_package_name
```

Which will publish your package's configuration file to:

```
app/config/packages/your_vendor_name/your_package_name
```

Where then you can change the `route_admin_index` at will.

If `php artisan config:publish` was not called. Your route will default back to what you have in your package's config file.

Comment: That would probably work. But is there any way to dynamically change the parameters sent to the route? Maybe a callback, but as I understand it configs don't support callback functions.